# Debugging Android BroadcastReceiver onReceive() method in Android Studio

Tags: android, debugging, android-studio, timeout, android-broadcastreceiver

I am new to Android development. I am using Android Studio 2.2.3
When I try to debug what happens when a class extends BroadcastReceiver and the 
onReceive() method is called I cannot because there is a timeout. I see this in the logs.

> Thread[5,tid=13474,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xf3c30c00,peer=0x12c0a0a0,"Signal
>   Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3

I understand from the docs that this is necessary because everything there has to happen fast, but is there no way of extending this timout period for debugging?  The code does not take a long time to run I just need more time in order to debug it.

My OS is Windows 10.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're seeing that message exactly, but I know you can debug onReceive() without issue—I have many times. Something else is going on that is causing that exception. Perhaps if you provided the appropriate code we could better help you.

Comment: Even if I download code from GitHub it does the same thing. I tried with home screed widgets.

Comment: Downloaded this https://github.com/MatthewDailey/late-counter-android breakpoint on on receive, debugger crashes in a few seconds.

Comment: Off-topic: But if you're having an issue with someone else's code on github, you might want to open an issue with the author there on github too.

Comment: I did, but as I said above, I have this issue with all onReceive() methods. I onlu found this code because I was searching for something similar to what I was doing and I wanted to see if my code was the problem. We are either both doing something wring or there is a configuration issue or as I read in rhe docs onReceive needs to complete very quickly, but the docs didn't have anything to say about how to debug onReceive in this case.

Comment: Have you tried it with another device and/or emulator?

Comment: I tried with genymotion and the official emulator that comes with android studio. Same thing.

Comment: Not a solution to the problem, but you can always revert to `Log.d()` debugging—not interrupting the thread but outputting whatever variables you need to inspect and continuing execution.

Comment: I was looking for something more ... permanent. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is somewhere between a work-around and a solution, but it works for me.
I went to the emulated device's Settings -> Developer Options and enabled "Show all ANRs" and now a warning appears "Your application is not responding" and I can tap "WAIT" and it seems to work.